# Conditional SQL Sum with double counting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has sales orders with amounts as well as a "type" field that could have multiple elements per amount.

orders would look like:

```
 1000  |  TypeA;TypeC
 5000  |  TypeA;TypeB
```

I'd like to sum up orders by type and double count an order when it has multiple types associated with it. Again, on the example above, TypeA=6000, TypeB = 5000, TypeC=1000.

I'm struggling with how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: `TypeA;TypeC` this is single text type column and types are separated by semicolon ?

Comment: can you have more than 2 types per amount? and why are you storing data delimited?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a separate table of types, I would suggest:

```
select t.type, sum(o.amount)
from types t left join
     orders o
     on find_in_set(t.type, replace(o.types, ';', ','))
group by t.type;
```

Without a separate table, you can put the values into columns:

```
select sum(case when find_in_set('TypeA', replace(o.types, ';', ',')) > 0 then amount else 0 end) as amount_A,
       sum(case when find_in_set('TypeB', replace(o.types, ';', ',')) > 0 then amount else 0 end) as amount_B,
       sum(case when find_in_set('TypeC', replace(o.types, ';', ',')) > 0 then amount else 0 end) as amount_C   
from orders o;
```

Two notes:

- Storing multiple values in a string column is not the SQLish way of storing values.  You should have one row per `order` and `type`.
- If you must, then at least use a comma, because MySQL has built in functions for working with a comma-delimited list.

Just to emphasize, a second table is much, much, much, much preferred to the second method.  But if you *have* to use a list -- say because someone who doesn't know better and controls your job insists -- then commas are better than semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to calculate the total like this (assuming the columns in the sample data named `col1` and `col2` :

```
SELECT SUM(IF(CONCAT(';',t.col2,';') LIKE '%;TypeA;%',t.col1,NULL)) AS TypeA
     , SUM(IF(CONCAT(';',t.col2,';') LIKE '%;TypeB;%',t.col1,NULL)) AS TypeB
     , SUM(IF(CONCAT(';',t.col2,';') LIKE '%;TypeC;%',t.col1,NULL)) AS TypeC
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE ...
```

This approach allows a value of `col1` to be conditionally included in multiple results, with one pass through `mytable`.